# Pointer not moving, mouse inputs still work in 16.10 live build

Tags: nvidia, 16.10, mouse-pointer

I'm trying to get 16.10 installed on my new PC (running a gtx 1080, and the mouse is a Logitech g502 if it matters) and my pointer is frozen in the top left corner of the screen, both in the installer, and in the live build from the USB.

Now, the mouse still *works*, I can click, and even move over different icons, but the visible pointer won't move, so navigation involves guessing where on the screen I am.

Any ideas about what might be causing this? Or at least keyboard-based ways to fix it? I've searched around quite a bit, but I haven't heard of anyone else having this issue. I just want to be able to install the OS properly.

Comment: Obvious question... does this happen with another mouse?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and from what I've read so far this seems to be a problem with newer Nvidia graphics cards (GTX 10xx) and the nouveau display driver.

To get my cursor working during installation I did the following:

1. Boot from CD/USB
2. In GRUB, select `Install 'your distroname'` but don't start it
3. Press the `e` key to change the boot paramters
4. In the line that starts with `linux` add  `nomodeset` in front of `quiet splash` so it looks like `nomodeset quiet splash`
5. Press F10 to boot with these options

Now the installer wasn't in my monitors native resolution but the mouse was working!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a fix
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZqcWfBINbY
Just activate the nividia drivers somehow

Comment: It would be better if you describe the steps of resolution.