# Mouse pointer doesn't move

Tags: mouse

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.10, but there's a problem. My mouse pointer doesn't want to move. I can still move the mouse and click on things (I can "guess" where the mouse will be), but the pointer on the screen stays in the top left. I've tried with 2 different mice (different brands), same result. This also happens across multiple linux distros. I'm at a loss of what it could be, suggestions?

Comment: @janos Nope! Both mice I tried are wired

Answer (score 0):

[This answer fixed my issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/885856/229759). I was using a GTX 1070 that didn't play nice with Ubuntu until I could get the right drivers installed.